# Got a bug while developing a Tic Tac Toe game in C++

Tags: c++

I was developing a Tic Tac Toe game in *C++* and I ended up with this bug that after chosing a position for my 'X' or 'O' to be in, the screen fills to no end with "that position is taken, please choose another one" (the text that shows by cout). I'd appreciate if some could help me out on this one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
char castigator(char c[3][3]) // Checking to see if and who won
{
  if(c[0][0]=='O'&&c[0][1]=='O'&&c[0][2]=='O')
    return 'O';
  if(c[0][0]=='O'&&c[1][0]=='O'&&c[2][0]=='O')
    return 'O';
  if(c[0][0]=='O'&&c[1][1]=='O'&&c[2][2]=='O')
    return 'O';
  if(c[0][1]=='O'&&c[1][1]=='O'&&c[2][1]=='O')
    return 'O';
  if(c[0][2]=='O'&&c[1][2]=='O'&&c[2][2]=='O')
    return 'O';
  if(c[1][0]=='O'&&c[1][1]=='O'&&c[1][2]=='O')
    return 'O';
  if(c[2][0]=='O'&&c[2][1]=='O'&&c[2][2]=='O')
    return 'O';
  if(c[0][2]=='O'&&c[1][2]=='O'&&c[2][2]=='O')
    return 'O';
  if(c[0][0]=='O'&&c[1][0]=='O'&&c[2][0]=='O')
    return 'O';
  if(c[0][1]=='O'&&c[1][1]=='O'&&c[2][1]=='O')
    return 'O';
 if(c[0][0]=='X'&&c[0][1]=='X'&&c[0][2]=='X')
    return 'X';
  if(c[0][0]=='X'&&c[1][0]=='X'&&c[2][0]=='X')
    return 'X';
  if(c[0][0]=='X'&&c[1][1]=='X'&&c[2][2]=='X')
    return 'X';
  if(c[0][1]=='X'&&c[1][1]=='X'&&c[2][1]=='X')
    return 'X';
  if(c[0][2]=='X'&&c[1][2]=='X'&&c[2][2]=='X')
    return 'X';
  if(c[1][0]=='X'&&c[1][1]=='X'&&c[1][2]=='X')
    return 'X';
  if(c[2][0]=='X'&&c[2][1]=='X'&&c[2][2]=='X')
    return 'X';
  if(c[0][2]=='X'&&c[1][2]=='X'&&c[2][2]=='X')
    return 'X';
  if(c[0][0]=='X'&&c[1][0]=='X'&&c[2][0]=='X')
    return 'X';
  if(c[0][1]=='X'&&c[1][1]=='X'&&c[2][1]=='X')
    return 'X';
}
char verificare(char c[3][3], int z) //checking if the position the player wants to put his 'X' or 'O' is free and return 1 if so
{if(z==1&&c[0][0]==1)
    return 1;
 else
    return 0;
 if(z==2&&c[0][1]==2)
    return 1;
 else
    return 0;
 if(z==3&&c[0][2]==3)
    return 1;
 else
    return 0;
 if(z==4&&c[1][0]==4)
    return 1;
 else
    return 0;
 if(z==5&&c[1][1]==5)
    return 1;
 else
    return 0;
 if(z==6&&c[1][2]==6)
    return 1;
 else
    return 0;
 if(z==7&&c[2][0]==7)
    return 1;
 else
    return 0;
 if(z==8&&c[2][1]==8)
    return 1;
 else
    return 0;
 if(z==9&&c[2][2]==9)
    return 1;
 else
    return 0;
}
void mutare(char c[3][3], int t1, int t2, int z) //making the move on the board by replacing the respective position with eithre 'X' or 'O'
{if(t1==1&&t2==0&&z==1) //t1 and t2 stands for turns to chechi which player's turn is it
c[0][0]='X';
if(t1==1&&t2==0&&z==2)
c[0][1]='X';
if(t1==1&&t2==0&&z==3)
c[0][2]='X';
if(t1==1&&t2==0&&z==4)
c[1][0]='X';
if(t1==1&&t2==0&&z==5)
c[1][1]='X';
if(t1==1&&t2==0&&z==6)
c[1][2]='X';
if(t1==1&&t2==0&&z==7)
c[2][0]='X';
if(t1==1&&t2==0&&z==8)
c[2][1]='X';
if(t1==1&&t2==0&&z==9)
c[2][2]='X';

if(t1==0&&t2==1&&z==1)
c[0][0]='O';
if(t1==0&&t2==1&&z==2)
c[0][1]='O';
if(t1==0&&t2==1&&z==3)
c[0][2]='O';
if(t1==0&&t2==1&&z==4)
c[1][0]='O';
if(t1==0&&t2==1&&z==5)
c[1][1]='O';
if(t1==0&&t2==1&&z==6)
c[1][2]='O';
if(t1==0&&t2==1&&z==7)
c[2][0]='O';
if(t1==0&&t2==1&&z==8)
c[2][1]='O';
if(t1==0&&t2==1&&z==9)
c[2][2]='O';

}
char afisare(char c[3][3]) //showing the matrix and its elements
{   system("cls");
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
      cout<<c[i][j]<<" ";
      cout<<endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    char c[3][3]={'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
    int t1=1,t2=0,z;
         afisare(c); //showing the matrix for the first time
    while(1)
        {afisare(c); 
          if(castigator(c)=='X') //if the return of the sub castigator is 'X' cout<<"The X player has won" and end the loop
          {cout<<"The 'X' player won";
           break;}
          else
            if(castigator(c)=='O') 
            {cout<<"The 'O' player won";
            break;}
        cout<<"What position do you want to choose?"<<" "; // to replace with your 'X' or 'O'
        cin>>z; //getting the position
        if(verificare(c,z)==1) //checking if the position is not taken
            mutare(c,t1,t2,z); //making the move by replacing the number with either 'X' or 'O'
        else
            {while(verificare(c,z)==0)//if the position is taken it asks for another position untill it finds one that isn't taken
                cout<<"That position is taken, please choose another one"<<" "; 
                cin>>z;
                if(verificare(c,z)==1)
                    mutare(c,t1,t2,z);
            }
        if(t1==1) //by now, the turn was made and if it was the t1 turn then, the next one will be to t2
            {t1=0;
            t2=1;}
        else
        {t1=1;
         t2=0;}
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger, and step through the code line by line, and the problem should be pretty obvious. It would also be obvious if you formatted your code a little differently, or let the editor you have reformat it for you.

Comment: If not a debugger, then just use print statements. But do something like that.

Comment: Function `afisare` should be declared with return type `void`. Than you compile. Your bug is `while(verificare(c,z)==0`. Without curly brackets the `while` apply only on the first statement. If you fix this, there are other errors and this is for debugger - please learn how to use it.

Comment: I got it running the right way in the end. I appreciate your help and advices. I'll use a debugger in the future.

Comment: you are having multiple `if(c[0][1]=='O'&&c[1][1]=='O'&&c[2][1]=='O')` and `if(c[0][0]=='O'&&c[1][0]=='O'&&c[2][0]=='O')` and also `if(c[0][2]=='O'&&c[1][2]=='O'&&c[2][2]=='O')` for both O and X. why?

Comment: @Himanshu I'm checking to see if a winning possibility has been met by checking every possibility for both X and O.

Comment: @FeciucTeodor, the conditions i have mentioned above, you have written twice in your code. you are checking same conditions twice.

Answer (score 1):

You put only the cout statement in the loop where you're checking the input.

```
while(verificare(c,z)==0)
  cout<<"That position is taken, please choose another one"<<" ";
  // END OF THE WHILE HERE
```

Use curly brackets to execute multiple statement in a loop, you could leave that only if you wanna put one statement in the loop!

```
while(verificare(c,z)==0) {
  cout<<"That position is taken, please choose another one"<<" ";
  // STILL IN THE LOOP
}
```

Comment: I just noticed that. Thank you, kind sir!